# Dot product with Einstein summation convention (index notation)

Tags: convention, index-notation

My professor, when proving:
$$a \cdot b = a_ib_i$$
wrote:
$$(a_i \hat{e}_i)\cdot(b_j \hat{e}_j) = (a_ib_j)(\hat{e}_i\hat{e}_j)$$

---

My doubt is:

*Are we allowed to treat the dot product as **ordinary multiplication** once we have written everything in index notations? Does the same go for cross product?*

---

1. The confusion is mainly because we have moved $b_j$ from one bracket to another.
   In my mind, We have moved $b_j$ **across the dot**. This feels wrong.
2. By '**ordinary multiplication**', I mean the kind of multiplication that we use in algebra to denote the product of two variables. We can move variables from one bracket to another there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in the right-hand side of

$(_̂_)⋅(_̂_)=(__)(̂_̂_)$

is not ordinary multiplication, because $̂_$ and $̂_$ are vectors. There you have to use the dot product.

Switching to the common notation we have:

$a=\sum_i a_i ̂_$

$b=\sum_j b_j ̂_j$

and
$$
a \cdot b= \sum_{i,j} a_i b_j (̂_ \cdot ̂_j)
$$
There we are using that the dot product is bilinear.

Comment: The cross product is distributive over addition, so we have $(̂ )x(̂ )=()(̂ x̂ )$